# saving table data in json file and again get when click a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a table which is editable. I want to save my table content after editing on click of a button. Then again when I click another button I want get this data back using JSON.

```js
$('.logodiv2').on('click', function() {
  var myjson = '{';
  var mainobject = [];
  var tbl2 = $('tr').each(function(tittle) {
    x = $(this).children();
    var subobject = [];
    x.each(function() {
      subobject.push('"' + $(this).text() + '"');
    });
    mainobject.push('"' + tittle + '": [' + subobject.join(',') + ']');
  })
  myjson += mainobject.join(",") + '}'
  alert(JSON.stringify(myjson));
  return myjson;
});
```

```html
<div class="logodiv1">
  <img src="images/folder.svg" />
</div>
<div class="logodiv2">
  <img src="images/saveicon.svg" />
</div>
```

Comment: No error occurred while test..! https://jsfiddle.net/smit_patel/uooeq8qk/

Comment: yes i get the data in a variable using  var k = (JSON.stringify(myjson)); but i want to save this using filname.js but i dont no how it done